# Как написать скрипт, который меняет структуру таблицы в дополнительном change-log'е?

Tags: sql, postgresql, h2, liquibase

Имеется Sping приложение, которое использует liquibase.

И представлен следующий change-log:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <databaseChangeLog
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
             http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">

        <include file="changelog/01-init.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
       <include file="changelog/02-change-table.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
       <include file="changelog/03-insert-table.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>

    </databaseChangeLog>
```

Как можно увидеть из структуры, данный change-log постепенно выполняет скрипты. Сначала инициализируется сама таблица, потом таблица изменяется и уже в конце вставляются данные.

```
01-init.sql -> 02-change-table.sql -> 03-insert-table.sql
```

01-init.sql DDL:

```
create table tmp
(
  id   bigint primary key,
  test VARCHAR(10)
);
```

02-change-table.sql script:

```
ALTER TABLE tmp RENAME COLUMN test TO tmp_test;
ALTER TABLE tmp ADD COLUMN test VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT 'UNKNOWN';
UPDATE tmp SET test = tmp_test WHERE tmp_test IN ('abc', 'hij');
```

03-insert-table.sql script:

```
insert into tmp (id, test) values (1, 'abc');
insert into tmp (id, test) values (2, null);
```

**Ожидаемое поведение**: второй скрипт должен накатить изменения, которые не позволяет вставлять в таблицу `tmp` значения **NULL**. Скрипт должен менять `test` на `UNKNOWN`, если оное поле не задано.

Но по факту что получаю при селекте:

```
select * from tmp;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если поменять местами накатывание changelog'ов, на:

```
 01-init.sql -> 03-insert-table.sql -> 02-change-table.sql
```

То в итоге всё работает как задумано:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос следующий:** Как правильно сделать changelog, чтобы поле `test` менялось на `UNKNOWN` в случае входного значения NULL, не меняя при этом последовательность выполнения скриптов `01-init.sql -> 02-change-table.sql -> 03-insert-table.sql`?

Может есть какой-нибудь триггер?

Comment: default значение это не NOT NULL, если вы его указали, это не значит что не можете вставить insert into tmp (id, test) values (2, null); Чтобы было дефаултное, инсертите без описания 2 столбца insert into tmp (id) values (2);

Comment: @xSx всё именно так. Но я немного не верно поставил вопрос, вероятно. Короче говоря, тут есть два варианта решения:

1) Сделать Not Null 
2) Написать триггер для каждого insert'а в таблицу.

Comment: Я не знаю, в чем вы формируете инсерты, но разве нельзя сделать так, чтобы сформировалось так? insert into tmp (id, test) values (1, isnull('abc','UNKNOWN'));
insert into tmp (id, test) values (2, isnull(null,'UNKNOWN'));